# How to create a single dimensional array containing 100 random integers and find the Average value, Standard Deviation and Variance?

Tags: java, arrays, mean, standard-deviation, variance

I tried attempting this but I think I'm doing something wrong. I am a beginner level programmer and I really need help on this. I feel like I'm close to the answer but I'm not sure what's wrong with my program. I try checking my answer by square rooting the Variance result to get Standard Deviation but they don't match.

```
    import java.util.Random;
    public class Lab6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("The Average Value is:"+avgValue());
    System.out.println("The Standard Deviation is:"+stdDev());
    System.out.println("The Variance is:"+Var());
    }

    public static int randomFill(){

    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt();
    return randomNum;
    }

    private static int[] anArray;

    public static int[] list() {
    anArray = new int[100];
    for(int i=0;i<anArray.length;i++)
    {
    anArray[i] = randomFill();
    }
    return anArray;
    }

    private static int sum;

    public static int avgValue() {
    int []a = list();
    for (int e:a)
    {
    sum +=e;
    }
    int n=100;
    sum=sum/n;
    return sum;
    }

    private static int pwr;

    public static int stdDev() {
    int []b = list(); 
    int dev=0;
    for (int e:b)
    {
    dev=(e-sum)+dev;
    }
    pwr=(dev*dev)/99;
    double root=Math.sqrt(pwr);
    return pwr;
    }

    public static int Var() {
    int c= pwr; 
    int opp=c*c; 
    return opp;
    }

    }
```

Comment: You have a number of formatting / logic issues, so it might be helpful to read a Java style guide, and carefully review your code. For example, in `stdDev()` the line `double root=Math.sqrt(pwr);` is useless - you don't do anything with the value `root`. In terms of accurate results, look carefully at how you compute `stdDev`: you need to take *the sum of squared deviations* but instead you are *squaring the sum of deviations*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its been a while since I did statistics but I can point out that your avgValue() method and your stdDev() are computing against two different int arrays. When you call list() you get a different array of integers each time and overwrite anArray.

I'd recommend creating the array inside your main method and then passing it as a parameter to the other methods. If you want to go the route you're on, change "int []b = list();" to "int []b = anArray;" and you should be fine.

Overall I think you might want to try looking into method parameters and variable scope next to improve your Java. Keep on truckin'; it gets easier.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall the variance and standard deviation formulas correctly, but one mistake related to programming logic in your code is that you have called `list()` once while calculating the average and once while calculating the standard deviation.

Every call to your `list()` method returns a new array with new random values. So, essentially, even if you calculate standard deviation correctly from the code, the average you consider (i.e the `sum` variable) corresponds to the average of some other array.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    int[] arr = createRandomArray(100);
    System.out.printf(Locale.US, "The Average Value is: %.2f\n", mean(arr));
    System.out.printf(Locale.US, "The Standard Deviation is: %.2f\n", standardDeviation(arr));
    System.out.printf(Locale.US, "The Variance is: %.2f\n", variance(arr));
}

public static int[] createRandomArray(int total) {
    int[] arr = new int[total];
    Random random = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        arr[i] = random.nextInt(100);

    return arr;
}

public static double mean(int[] arr) {
    return (double)Arrays.stream(arr).sum() / arr.length;
}

public static double standardDeviation(int[] arr) {
    double mean = mean(arr);

    double sum = IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
                          .boxed()
                          .map(i -> Math.pow(arr[i] - mean, 2))
                          .mapToDouble(d -> d)
                          .sum();

    return Math.sqrt(sum / arr.length);
}

public static double variance(int[] arr) {
    return Math.pow(standardDeviation(arr), 2);
}
```